# how to tell Inline ASM the variable is in hex

Tags: c++, visual-c++, assembly

I am trying to use the following code

```
__declspec(naked) void StubStart()
{
    __asm{
        MOV EAX, oep
        JMP EAX
    }
}
```

and I wanted to tell it that the "oep" variable is in hex, but I think I cannot put both (0x and h) to tell it, it is in hex.
what can I do?

Comment: What do you mean by `oep is in hex`? Is it not an int-type variable?

Comment: yes, i think my problem is can I put a variable on an inline asm and will it take the value of the variable if the variable changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `oep` variable is most likely just an `int` (or some other integral type).

Regardless if you did

```
oep = 0x55;
```

or

```
oep = 55;
```

it will ultimately be represented in binary in the computer... you can't say that a variable contains a hexadecimal value, decimal value or octal value... it contains an integer.

Comment: ok thanks but when I put the original value like 0x23F56 it works fine but when I use the variable it failes..

Comment: what I mean is passing fro example 128 in hex is not equal to passing 128 in decimal. the two numbers are not equal.

Comment: Where ever you got that number from, you should have *parsed* it in base 16, instead of in base 10.